# How to find parameters of an optimization function by using scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to replicate this paper: [Global motion estimation from coarsely sampled motion vector field and the applications](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=1390998)

I need to find the parameters `m0, m1, m2....., m7`
Given a images x1_1 and x1_2 and where the equations are

[Example data.](http://pastebin.com/VutTTTSM)

[image]

Where x'{x1_2[1, :, :]} and y'{x1_2[0, :, :]} are values of x1_2 and
x, y the x1_1 is x1_1 in the same style.

I have refereed to the example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242979/fit-multiple-parametric-curves-with-scipy) to make this implementation.

Could anyone help me how to find these parameters?

## Made edits as per comments and the [example of `leastsq` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq).

## Changed program is given below and output is given below

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


def peval (inp_mat,p):
    m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7 = p
    out_mat = np.zeros(inp_mat.shape,dtype=np.float32)
    mid = inp_mat.shape[0]/2
    for xy in range(0,inp_mat.shape[0]):
        if (xy<(inp_mat.shape[0]/2)):
            out_mat[xy] = ( (  (inp_mat[xy+mid]*m0)+(inp_mat[xy]*m1)+ m2 ) /( (inp_mat[xy+mid]*m6)+(inp_mat[xy]*m7)+1 ) )
        else:
            out_mat[xy] = ( (  (inp_mat[xy]*m3)+(inp_mat[xy-mid]*m4)+ m5 ) /( (inp_mat[xy]*m6)+(inp_mat[xy-mid]*m7)+1 ) )
    return out_mat

def residuals(p, out_mat, inp_mat):
    m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7 = p
    err=np.zeros(inp_mat.shape,dtype=np.float32)
    if (out_mat.shape == inp_mat.shape):
        for xy in range(0,inp_mat.shape[0]):
            err[xy] =  err[xy]+ (out_mat[xy] -inp_mat[xy])
        return err




f = open('/media/anilil/Data/Datasets/repo/txt_op/vid.txt','r')
x = np.loadtxt(f,dtype=np.int16,comments='#',delimiter='\t')
nof = x.shape[0]/72 # Find the number of frames
x1 = x.reshape(-1,60,40)
x1_1= x1[0,:,:].flatten()
x1_2= x1[1,:,:].flatten()

x= []
y= []

for xy in range(1,50,1):
    y.append(x1[xy,:,:].flatten())
    x.append(x1[xy-1,:,:].flatten())

x=np.array(x,dtype=np.float32)
y=np.array(y,dtype=np.float32)
length =  x1_1.shape#initail guess
p0 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],dtype=np.float32)

abc=leastsq(residuals, p0,args=(y,x))
print ('Size of first matrix is '+str(x1_1.shape))
print ('Size of first matrix is '+str(x1_2.shape))

print ("Done with program")
```

## Output

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/anilil/Data/charm/mv_clean/.idea/nose_reduction_mpeg.py", line 49, in <module>
    abc=leastsq(residuals, p0,args=(y,x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 378, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: Could you share the data you are using?!

Comment: `opt.leastsq` takes a function handle, but you call `function()` before passing it to `leastsq`. Remove the `()` in order to pass the function itself, without calling it first: `opt.leastsq(function, args=(), Dfun=...`.  This should make the error message go away, but I don't know if everything else is correct.

Comment: Shared the example data and tried the ´function´ instead of ´function()´
@kazemakase

Comment: Ah, i missed that, first. You also have to pass an `x0` to the function: `opt.leastsq(function, x0, args=(), ...`. These are the starting values (the starting guess) for the parameters `m0`...`m7` you optimize. This is very domain specific, and I don't know what good values may be. You can try 0s, or maybe the paper can give you a hint where to start. Also, `inp_mat` sounds like it is data and not an optimization parameter. Thus, I don't think it should be a function argument.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [documentation of `leastsq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html) and [the example](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/optimize.html#least-square-fitting-leastsq).

You need to define the objective function so that it takes all the parameters as the first argument, followed by other inputs:

```
def function (M, inp_mat):
    m0, m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7 = M
    out_mat = np.zeros(inp_mat.shape)
    ...
```

The other parameters, in your case `inp_mat`, are passed as `args` to the optimization function:

```
result = opt.leastsq(function, x0, args=(inp_mat), Dfun=None, full_output=0, col_deriv=0, ftol=1.49012e-08, xtol=1.49012e-08, gtol=0.0, maxfev=0, epsfcn=None, factor=100, diag=None)
```

I don't know what `inp_mat` is supposed to be. Most likely it has something to do with the data, so `args=(x1)` is probably what you want.

Finally, you want to retrieve the result from the optimization and do something with them.

Comment: I made a few changes based on the example. But it seems there is still an error here.